# why are empty numpy arrays not printed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I initialise a python list

```
x = [[],[],[]]
print(x)
```

then it returns

```
[[], [], []]
```

but if I do the same with a numpy array

```
x = np.array([np.array([]),np.array([]),np.array([])])
print(x)
```

then it only returns

```
[]
```

How can I make it return a nested empty list as it does for a normal python list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually *does* return a nested empty list. For example, try

```
x = np.array([np.array([]),np.array([]),np.array([])])
>>> array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=float64)
```

or

```
>>> print x.shape
(3, 0)
```

Don't let the output of `print x` fool you. These types of outputs merely reflect the (aesthetic) choices of the implementors of `__str__` and `__repr__`. To actually see the exact dimension, you need to use things like `.shape`.

Answer (score 3):

To return a nested empty list from a numpy array, you can do:

```
x.tolist()
[[], [], []]
```

However, even if it prints only `[]`, the shape is correct:

```
x.shape
(3, 0)
```

And you can access any element like a list:

```
x[0]
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: `tolist` is a clever idea here.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for you is to convert it to a list with `tolist`

```
x = np.array([np.array([]),np.array([]),np.array([])])
print(x)
[]

print(x.tolist())
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: `tolist` is a clever idea here.